# How can I run scripts that can be written in different languages on the server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, server, codemirror

On my website (written in **Flask**) there is a CodeMirror code editor where you can choose one of the following programming languages to run the code: *PascalABC*, *Python 3*, *C++*, *Java*, *C#*.

For example in editor we have: [link to the screenshot of editor](https://i.postimg.cc/1XkV8yWS/image.png)

Is there any universal solution for getting the results of the program?

Comment: you can use standard module [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to run any program. For some languages you have to first run compiler to create .exe file and later run this .exe file. But servers like `CodeMirror` may do it in more complex way - they can run code in `virtual machines` so programs don't share memory, disk, etc with system on server - all for security reason.

Comment: @furas I've already written code to start python from python, can I gat more examples of running others languages on python?

Comment: Python: `subprocess.run(["/full/path/to/python.exe", "code.py"])`, PHP: `subprocess.run(["/full/path/to/php.exe", "code.php"])`, Other languages need to use `compilers + linkers` before running compiled code so it may need more commands and maybe first learn how to run `C++`/`Java`/`C#`/`Pascal` code directly in system, and next put all commands in script which you will run in `subprocess.run` - ie. C++ may need first `gcc code.cpp -o output.exe`, and next `output.exe`, and sometimes it may need also to use program `link` after `gcc`.

Comment: Thank you, I`ll try it, but at the moment i found another one way to run almost any language. Hese is [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/), i use their API and ajax requests to get results of running of programs